# Issue in JOIN query in apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

File stored in Hive:

```
[
  {
    "occupation": "guitarist",
    "fav_game": "football",
    "name": "d1"
  },
  {
    "occupation": "dancer",
    "fav_game": "chess",
    "name": "k1"
  },
  {
    "occupation": "traveller",
    "fav_game": "cricket",
    "name": "p1"
  },
  {
    "occupation": "drummer",
    "fav_game": "archery",
    "name": "d2"
  },
  {
    "occupation": "farmer",
    "fav_game": "cricket",
    "name": "k2"
  },
  {
    "occupation": "singer",
    "fav_game": "football",
    "name": "s1"
  }
]
```

CSV file in hadoop:

```
name,age,city
d1,23,delhi
k1,23,indore
p1,23,blore
d2,25,delhi
k2,30,delhi
s1,25,delhi
```

I queried them individually, it's working fine. Then, I tried join query:

```
select * from hdfs.`/demo/distribution.csv` d join hive.demo.`user_details` u on d.name = u.name
```

I got the following issue:

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: DrillRuntimeException: Join only supports implicit casts between 1. Numeric data 2. Varchar, Varbinary data 3. Date, Timestamp data Left type: INT, Right type: VARCHAR. Add explicit casts to avoid this error Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: b01db9c8-fb35-4ef8-a1c0-31b68ff7ae8d on IMPETUS-DSRV03.IMPETUS.CO.IN:31010]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/
We need to do explicit typecasting to deal with such scenario.

Consider we have a JSON file employee.json and a csv file sample.csv. In order to query on both at the same time , in one query we need to do type casting.

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select emp.employee_id, dept.department_description, phy.columns[2], phy.columns[3] FROM cp.`employee.json` emp , cp.`department.json` dept, dfs.`/tmp/sample.csv` phy where CAST(emp.employee_id AS INT) =  CAST(phy.columns[0] AS INT) and emp.department_id = dept.department_id;
```

Here we are typecasting **CAST(emp.employee_id AS INT) =  CAST(phy.columns[0] AS INT)** so that equality does not fail.

Refer this for more detail:- http://www.devinline.com/2015/11/apache-drill-setup-and-SQL-query-execution.html#multiple_src

Comment: I am joining on name and in both csv and json its string.

Comment: Yes,Its okay. But when you have CSV file it will report this error. If you had two JSON file then it will not pops up the same. 
One of possible reason may be different data source other than JSON(Since internally drill uses Schema-free JSON document model,for other data source it requires explicit casting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast even though by default it has taken varchar. Try this:

```
select * from hdfs.`/demo/distribution.csv` d join hive.demo.`user_details` u on cast(d.name as VARCHAR) = cast(u.name as VARCHAR)
```

But you cannot refer to column name directly from csv. you need to consider columns[0] for name.